# After importing sessions recorded in Fiddler to jmeter, not able to run the sessions

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, fiddler

I wanted to do performance testing on the mobile application, tried to record sessions through JMeter with the android studio emulator which was not working and then tried with fiddler tool and was able to record sessions. But when I try to import those sessions to Jmeter I saved as HAR file and then converted to jmx file and made to run in Jmeter. The sessions/samplers were in read telling not able to make request and was able to connect and get response from the emulator. Is there anything I'm missing here? or Is there any other method to test performance of mobile applications?

Comment: Fiddler Classic has some problems with the generated certificates. I would recommend to install "CertMaker for iOS and Android" plugin https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config which replaces certificate generation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say anything without seeing your .jar and .jmx files and knowing how did you "convert" the .har.  Theoretically you could take a look into .har file using your favourite text/json editor and create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)s manually.

In general it is possible to record Android application network activity using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) but you need to take some extra steps:

1. Import JMeter's certificate to your emulator
2. [Configure the emulator to use JMeter as the proxy](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#proxy)
3. Amend your application [network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) like it's described in [Configure Android Devices for Proxy Recording](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354685999889-Configure-Android-Devices-for-Proxy-Recording) article
4. You should be able to record now